# How to set env var for .npmrc use

Tags: node.js, npm, package.json, npm-scripts

I need a module in my project to download a private npm package. To accomplish this, I am using a `.npmrc` file to supply a read-only token needed to download the package. To keep the token supplied by npm out of the file, I wish to add it as an environment variable and let it expand in the file. E.g:

```
# .npmrc
//registry.npmjs.org/:_authToken=${NPM_TOKEN}
```

I can't figure out how to get that `NPM_TOKEN` added to the env before it is referenced for the install. I tried using an npm preinstall script:

`"preinstall": "NPM_READ_ONLY_TOKEN=my_token_goes_here_foo_bar"`**

But I still get the same error:

```
Error: Failed to replace env in config: ${NPM_READ_ONLY_TOKEN}
```

I tried testing with an echo command to see if `preinstall` runs before the .npmrc variable expansion, but it apparently does not. I would get the error and not see my echo log. I seem to be missing something here.

I'm aware that putting my token in package.json defeats the purpose of pulling the token out of the .npmrc file. I'm actually using a service that provides env config services that I would use to run a command and get the needed token. E.g. `TOKEN=config_service_value`.

Comment: A note for those wondering, preinstall script is run when your project/library is installed as a dependency by another project

Answer (score 52):

You can add the environment variable to your `.bashrc` or other startup shell file.

`export NPM_TOKEN=my_token_goes_here_foo_bar`

Comment: For those in a hurry like me that do not read the question thoroughly, an environment variable is not sufficient, the .npmrc file is also required, containing `//registry.npmjs.org/:_authToken=${NPM_TOKEN}`

Comment: THE RIGHT ANSWER - I tried ~250 different articles & answers within three days. https://stackoverflow.com/a/61666885/3748178

Comment: this doesn't work for me and I do have the env vars in my .bashrc before nvm is loaded.

Comment: @SalathielGenèse same here! Thanks for pointing me to the correct answer!!!

Answer (score 6):

If you are using `zsh` for your terminal. You should put the environment variable in the `.zshenv` file.

```
echo "export NPM_TOKEN=token_goes_here" >> ~/.zshenv
```

Then you have to restart your terminal and then try `echo $NPM_TOKEN`, you should be seeing the value of the environment variable.

Or send to `.bashrc` if you use bash.

Answer (score 5):

Here is how one would set an environment variable in Powershell (Windows 10):

```
$env:ENV_VARIABLE = 'Value of my environment variable'
```

And here is the [reference link](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/how-to-set-environment-variables-using-powershell) for further study

Answer (score 1):

The easy and working way:

1. You create '.npmrc.example' file, put there the registry address and commit this file to repo.
2. locally you manually copy the '.npmrc.example' file, rename it to just regular '.npmrc' and add your token to that file. Regular .npmrc MUST NOT be commited to the repo.