# Yarn with .npmrc and authentication

Tags: node.js, authentication, npm, yarnpkg

I have encountered an issue that I'm not sure how to resolve in the best way possible. Here it is:

We have recently started using private NPM packages, and are trying to figure out how to tie our local development loop with CI and a Deployment pipeline.

I've looked and started leveraging the NPM_TOKEN variable.
In CI, we are doing the following:

```
echo "//registry.yarnpkg.com/:_authToken=$NPM_TOKEN" >> ~/.npmrc
```

This works well, but during deployment on Heroku, we don't have access to home. So to make it work on Heroku we added an .npmrc file to the project directory. This worked well since npm uses environment variables to fill this in.

The problem is that locally, all yarn commands fail with a missing variable. The suggested way on the NPM website (https://blog.npmjs.org/post/118393368555/deploying-with-npm-private-modules) is to add the token to the environment in a .profile. This doesn't seem like the best solution, since the setting is now global, and should be kept per repository.

I've found a similar question here that uses npm but it does not seem to work with yarn.
[Using auth tokens in .npmrc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53099434/using-auth-tokens-in-npmrc)
A comment there also mentions that it does not work for npm and there is no documentation that mention a dotenv file.

Is there a better way to deal with this? Seems like a common issue that should be resolved a long time ago...

Comment: Which version of yarn are you using

Answer (score 7):

Use a [.yarnrc file](https://yarnpkg.com/configuration/yarnrc):

```
npmRegistryServer: "https://npm.pkg.github.com"
npmAuthToken: "secretAuthTokenValue"
```

Comment: But isn't .yarnrc file also used for general level configuration related to yarn, that should be put to version control? Like nodeLinker: node-modules. But you can't of course put it to version control if it consists sensitive information like npmAuthToken

Answer (score 2):

Faced this issue today with Azure Artifacts.

Following their [documented project setup](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/artifacts/npm/npmrc?view=azure-devops), the auto-generated code on Azure DevOps encodes the `@` symbol to `%40` in the `<FEED_NAME>` which caused `yarn add artifacts_package_name` to return a `401 Unauthorized` error:

```sh
# .npmrc doc example
//pkgs.dev.azure.com/<ORGANIZATION_NAME>/_packaging/<FEED_NAME>/npm/registry/
# .npmrc auto generated code on AzureDevOps
//pkgs.dev.azure.com/<ORGANIZATION_NAME>/_packaging/<ORGANIZATION_NAME%40Local>/npm/registry/
```

Issue was fixed by replacing all occurrences of `%40` with `@` like:

```sh
//pkgs.dev.azure.com/<ORGANIZATION_NAME>/_packaging/<ORGANIZATION_NAME@Local>/npm/registry/
```

**[source](https://github.com/yarnpkg/yarn/issues/4451#issuecomment-726818715)**

Answer (score 1):

Yarn 1.x will not replace the environment variable in the .npmrc or .yarnrc file; you must use a literal value.

Since you shouldn't commit tokens directly in the repo, the best solution is to add to your CI pipeline:

```
npm set //your.repo/:_authToken $THE_TOKEN_VALUE
```

**Using `yarn config set` will not work**.

Comment: Does this work with a scoped package (like @myorg/mypackage) ?

Comment: Yes; you need to also run `npm config set @myorg:registry http://myrepo.com`

Answer (score 0):

In my experience this can be a bit tricky. It feels like the sources you provided should give the best guidance. There is a .yarnrc file that I guess is linkied to the npmrc file as well. Anyway I can at least share a set up that I used in a project that worked for me: (this is from an older project so it might not be relevant anymore. If it isn't, let me know and I can remove this answer)

.npmrc file:

```
_auth = token
registry = http://example.com
ca = null
email = email@example.com
always-auth = true
```

.yarnrc file:

```
registry "http://example.com"
```