# NPM authentication for private module with Google App Engine

Tags: node.js, google-app-engine, npm, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-build

I am trying to deploy a node application which imports a private npm module to Google App Engine. I'm still stuck at `npm install` failing due to `Unable to authenticate, need: Basic realm="GitHub Package Registry"`.

One method of npm authentication is via the `NODE_AUTH_TOKEN` environment variable. GAE does not accept environment variables via the command line, only `app.yaml`, so I added my token to the app.yaml during my Github Actions CI process. It turns out that App Engine uses a separate Cloud Build environment to build which doesn't have this environment variable; therefore, failure again. I also tried creating a `cloudbuild.yaml` and subbed in my environment variable but no luck there. Lastly, I've tried to set my key via `.npmrc` like so:

```
//npm.pkg.github.com/gw-cocoon/:_authToken=$NPM_TOKEN
@gw-cocoon:registry=https://npm.pkg.github.com/gw-cocoon
```

and subbed in the token during CI. This fails for the same reason but I am not sure why. This token is autogenerated on each CI run so I cannot use Google Cloud KMS.

Comment: Does [Installing packages from github npm registry - auth error 401](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58919401/installing-packages-from-github-npm-registry-auth-error-401) answer your question? Also may be worth checking out this [GitHub issue](https://github.com/actions/setup-node/issues/52) on the subject from September.

Answer (score 1):

I was disappointed to find that [using private npm modules with App Engine Standard](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/143810864) is apparently not supported at all. This seems like a pretty glaring limitation given the rising popularity of GitHub packages etc for building modular (private) applications.

Interestingly, Google Cloud Functions [apparently supports](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/writing/specifying-dependencies-nodejs#using_private_modules) private npm modules, so perhaps it's just a matter of timing to gain support in App Engine.

Comment: Just found this related question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61114288/use-private-npm-registry-for-google-app-engine-standard