# GitHub action in GitHub Enterprise giving 401 and 404s on npm packages

Tags: github, npm, npm-install, github-actions, github-enterprise

I am using [semantic version action](https://github.com/cycjimmy/semantic-release-action) on my GitHub enterprise repository. It was working fine until recently, where it started failing with [this error](https://github.com/cycjimmy/semantic-release-action/issues/78)

```
Error: Command failed: npm ci --only=prod
npm ERR! code E401
npm ERR! Unable to authenticate, need: Basic realm="GitHub Package Registry"

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /root/.npm/_logs/2021-08-23T10_41_00_344Z-debug.log

    at ChildProcess.exithandler (child_process.js:295:12)
    at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:210:5)
    at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:1021:16)
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:283:5) {
  killed: false,
  code: 1,
  signal: null,
  cmd: 'npm ci --only=prod',
  stdout: '',
  stderr: 'npm ERR! code E401\n' +
    'npm ERR! Unable to authenticate, need: Basic realm="GitHub Package Registry"\n' +
    '\n' +
    'npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:\n' +
    'npm ERR!     /root/.npm/_logs/2021-08-23T10_41_00_344Z-debug.log\n'
```

The action I use is not expected to publish anything to GitHub Package Registry, maybe only read from Package Registry. So after googling I found this on SO and elsewhere - https://stackoverflow.com/a/63243950/1182982

So I updated my action to look like this now (I added the step: Setup node, it wasn't there before)

```
#===============================================================================
#===========================      Semamtic Version    ==========================
#===============================================================================
    semver:
        name: Semantic Versioning
        runs-on: [self-hosted, linux, x64]
        steps:
        - name: Setup node
          run: |
            echo "//npm.pkg.github.com/:_authToken=${{ secrets.GITHUBCOM_TOKEN }}" >> ~/.npmrc
            echo "@yrshaikh:registry=https://npm.pkg.github.com" >> ~/.npmrc
            echo 'registry "https://registry.yarnpkg.com"' >> ~/.yarnrc
        - uses: actions/checkout@v2
        - name: Semantic Release
          id: semantic
          # https://github.com/cycjimmy/semantic-release-action
          uses: internal-front-end/semantic-release-action@v2
        outputs:
          new_release_published: ${{ steps.semantic.outputs.new_release_published }}
          new_release_version: ${{ steps.semantic.outputs.new_release_version }}
```

Note, the `GITHUBCOM_TOKEN` I created using my github.com personal profile (And gave read packages/repo access) and `OWNER_NAME` in `@yrshaikh:registry=https://npm.pkg.github.com` I have filled in github.com user id.

After doing these changes the 401 authentication error has gone.

But I see a different error, which I have not been able to resolve -

```
Error: Command failed: npm --loglevel error ci --only=prod
npm ERR! code E404
npm ERR! 404 Not Found - GET https://npm.pkg.github.com/@actions%2fcore - npm package "core" does not exist under owner "actions"
npm ERR! 404 
npm ERR! 404  '@actions/core@1.2.7' is not in the npm registry.
npm ERR! 404 You should bug the author to publish it (or use the name yourself!)
npm ERR! 404 
npm ERR! 404 Note that you can also install from a
npm ERR! 404 tarball, folder, http url, or git url.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /root/.npm/_logs/2021-08-25T05_40_28_115Z-debug.log

    at ChildProcess.exithandler (child_process.js:295:12)
    at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:210:5)
    at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:1021:16)
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:283:5) {
  killed: false,
  code: 1,
  signal: null,
  cmd: 'npm --loglevel error ci --only=prod',
  stdout: '',
  stderr: 'npm ERR! code E404\n' +
    'npm ERR! 404 Not Found - GET https://npm.pkg.github.com/@actions%2fcore - npm package "core" does not exist under owner "actions"\n' +
    'npm ERR! 404 \n' +
    "npm ERR! 404  '@actions/core@1.2.7' is not in the npm registry.\n" +
    'npm ERR! 404 You should bug the author to publish it (or use the name yourself!)\n' +
    'npm ERR! 404 \n' +
    'npm ERR! 404 Note that you can also install from a\n' +
    'npm ERR! 404 tarball, folder, http url, or git url.\n' +
    '\n' +
    'npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:\n' +
    'npm ERR!     /root/.npm/_logs/2021-08-25T05_40_28_115Z-debug.log\n'
}
```

Any help or direction will be appreciated.

Comment: What's `/root/.npm/_logs/2021-08-25T05_40_28_115Z-debug.log`?

Answer (score 2):

There doesn't seem to be anything wrong about the `~/.npmrc`:

```
@${OWNER}:registry=https://npm.pkg.github.com
//npm.pkg.github.com/:_authToken=${TOKEN}
```

Have you tried to regenerate that personal access token? Be aware that these secrets also have scopes, so they may resolve in a private repository, but not necessarily a public repository.

`$GITHUB_TOKEN` may not have sufficient [permissions](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/reference/authentication-in-a-workflow#permissions-for-the-github_token); try adding a [personal access token](https://docs.github.com/en/github/authenticating-to-github/creating-a-personal-access-token) instead.

What does `npm login --scope=@yrshaikh --registry=https://npm.pkg.github.com` give?