# Node project installing a github private package in a github action workflow under the same account

Tags: github, github-actions, npm-install

The github document really confuses me. What should I exactly do to insall a package in github package inside github actions?

On the github action workflow, the document recommends to use `GITHUB_TOKEN`. But I can not see how to use it in a Node project for `npm install`.

workflow

```
on: push

jobs:
  install-package:
    permissions:
      packages: read
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v4
      - name: Use Node.js
        uses: actions/setup-node@v3
        with:
          node-version: 18.x
      - run: npm i
```

.npmrc

```
// MY_SCOPE is my account name.
@MY_SCOPE:registry=https://npm.pkg.github.com
```

error

```
npm ERR! code E401
npm ERR! 401 Unauthorized - GET https://npm.pkg.github.com/@MY_PACKAGE - authentication token not provided

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in: /home/runner/.npm/_logs/2023-11-13T04_23_29_816Z-debug-0.log
Error: Process completed with exit code 1.
```

*Both the private package and the project which intend to install it are under the same account.

Comment: Is that a private package?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Installing packages from github npm registry - auth error 401](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58919401/installing-packages-from-github-npm-registry-auth-error-401)

Comment: No it doesn't. But I have figured out just now.

Answer (score 0):

I've figured this out just now. I added `GITHUB_TOKEN` into .npmrc after the checkout action.

*According to the comment from @Azeem, this works only in my case where a package and a project which intend to install it are under the same account. If you need to install a package in github registry, it requires to use PAT for installing it.

workflow

```
on: push

jobs:
  install-package:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v4
      // Add the token value into .npmrc
      - run: echo -e "\n//npm.pkg.github.com/:_authToken=${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}" >> ./.npmrc
      - name: Use Node.js
        uses: actions/setup-node@v3
        with:
          node-version: 18.x
      - run: npm i
```

Comment: Trying to install it in the same repo (scope) with another workflow?

Comment: Explicitly adding `GITHUB_TOKEN`.

Comment: Publishing and installing in the same workflow under different jobs?

Comment: No. Publishing workflow is done in the package’s workflow and installing occurs in the project’s workflow. I might not understand your intention.

Comment: You're publishing a private package. Your answer suggests that you're publishing and installing under the same scope. That's why you don't need a PAT. Right?

Comment: In my case, yes. So PAT is required different scope such as different organization?

Comment: Right. Yes. That's why I originally marked it as a duplicate. But, your use case is different. You might want to update your question with this critical information for future readers. Thanks!

Comment: I did understand. Than you for your help.

Comment: Sure, no problem. Installing a public package should not be an issue, it's the private package that becomes an issue. See [Authenticating to GitHub Packages](https://docs.github.com/en/packages/learn-github-packages/introduction-to-github-packages#authenticating-to-github-packages) for more details.