How to set the registry URL in a project-level .npmrc file from an environment variable in an Azure Pipeline
I have a project level .npmrc with private npm registry url
registry=https://blabla.pkgs.visualstudio.com/_packaging/BlaBla/npm/registry/  
                        
always-auth=true

and my Azure pipeline has this stage for npm install using their built in task
          - task: Npm@1
            displayName: "NPM Install"
            inputs:
              command: custom
              workingDir: ./project/  #this is the project folder, has package.json, npmrc files
              customCommand: install
              verbose: true

Now this works fine and packages are installed. I think the authentication token is stored in some global .npmrc file
Problem
Due to compliance issues I cannot store the URL hardcoded in the .npmrc since it is committed and scanned and complained by code analysis tools.
What I tried
I tried to somehow set it like an environment variable
Approach 1
I edited my project level npmrc
registry=$REGISTRY 
always-auth=true

and wrote a bash stage before the install
          - bash: |
              export NPM_CONFIG_REGISTRY=https://blabla.pkgs.visualstudio.com/_packaging/BlaBla/npm/registry/
              echo $NPM_CONFIG_REGISTRY  #hardcoded in pipeline for testing
            displayName: "Set NPM Registry"
            workingDir: $(Build.SourcesDirectory)/project/

This didn't work in the pipeline and gave npm ERR! code ERR_INVALID_URL. When I tried this locally also it seems that it adds the registry URL globally because when I tested with npm config get registry it printed the URL I just set both in the project folder level (has project level npmrc) and outside the project folder.
I also tested while the url was hardcoded and npm config get registry printed the correct URL in the project folder and outside it printed https://registry.npmjs.org/. But locally the npm install worked but probably for the wrong reasons since it also gave this
npm WARN invalid config registry="$REGISTRY" set in C:\BlaBla\project\.npmrc
npm WARN invalid config Must be full url with "http://"

So in conclusion I think the project level registry URL was never set even locally but I don't know why the Azure pipeline didn't even come this close. My guess is the NPM task runs in a different terminal/session so it doesn't have an idea of the env variable I just set
Approach 2
Instead of setting an env I edited my install custom command
customCommand: install --registry https://blabla.pkgs.visualstudio.com/_packaging/BlaBla/npm/registry/
now also the I got the same npm WARN but instead of the invalid URL errors this time I got
npm ERR! code E401
npm ERR! Unable to authenticate, your authentication token seems to be invalid.

What can I try next to resolve this?
Resources used: https://stackoverflow.com/a/55441931/13583510

Have you tried setting NPM_CONFIG_REGISTRY as a pipeline variable? They get injected as environment variables for the whole pipeline (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml%2Cbatch#environment-variables)

If your pipeline and feed are in the same org, I suggest that you can directly set the customRegistry and customFeed in the Buit-in Npm task.  This can omit the extra settings in .npmrc.  This should make it easier for you to configure the pipeline to run your project


How to set the registry URL in a project-level .npmrc file from an environment variable in an Azure Pipeline

Your guess is correct. When you use export command in bash to set the environment  variable, it can only work on current session. And NPM task is working on different session. So it can not read the correct environemnt.
To meet your requirement, you can directly define the Pipeline Variable with the feed url and set the format: ${REGISTRY} to use environment variable in npmrc file.
Here is an example:
.npmrc file:
registry=${REGISTRY}                        
always-auth=true

Pipeline Sample:
variables:
  REGISTRY: 'https://blabla.pkgs.visualstudio.com/_packaging/BlaBla/npm/registry'

steps:
.... Other steps

- task: Npm@1
  displayName: "NPM Install"
  inputs:
    command: custom
    workingDir: ./project/  #this is the project folder, has package.json, npmrc files
    customCommand: install
    verbose: true

Result:  We can see valid NPM registry url in NPM task.

On the other hand, I would like to share another easier method to use private feed. If your pipeline and feed are in the same organization, you can directly set the customRegistry and customFeed in NPM task.
For example:
- task: Npm@1
  displayName: "NPM Install"
  inputs:
    command: 'custom'
    workingDir: './project/'
    customCommand: 'install'
    customRegistry: 'useFeed'
    customFeed: 'Your Feed Name'

In this case, you don't need to set any additional configurations in project .npmrc file.
Update:
When we use Pipeline Environment variable in NPM task to replace the registry value in .npmrc file, it may not automatically set the credentials for the registry and cause 401 error.
If you run into this issue, you can consider using sed command to replace the registry url before the npm task.
Here is an example:
.npmrc file:
registry=InputREGISTRY          
always-auth=true

Pipeline sample:
variables:
  REGISTRY: https://blabla.pkgs.visualstudio.com/_packaging/BlaBla/npm/registry/ 

steps:
- bash: sed -i 's,registry=InputREGISTRY,registry=$(REGISTRY),g' $(Build.SourcesDirectory)/project/.npmrc 
- task: Npm@1
  displayName: "NPM Install"
  inputs:
    command: custom
    workingDir: ./project/  
    customCommand: install
    verbose: true


Thanks for the many suggestions. I tried the first solution and it failed even though it seemed to set the url. The sed one passed. Here is the difference I saw between the passed and the failed. Is this what you meant by the it may not automatically set the credentials. I'll also try the second easier approach

in fact instead of the sed i did npm config set registry -L project $(REGISTRY) (thanks to this comment) under workingDirectory $(Build.SourcesDirectory)/project/

@cmgchess Yes. This is indeed the 401 issue I mentioned. We need to make sure that the registry url has been update in .npmrc file before running npm task. In this case, it will automatically set the credentials. The sed command can achieve this requirement in pipeline.

@cmgchess But I really recommend you to use the simple method: set the customRegistry and customFeed in the Buit-in Npm task. Please have a try and feel free to let me know if it can work for you.

in that approach do we need the npmrc at all? Update: Ok just tested without the npmrc and it worked!

@cmgchess We can even remove project .npmrc file.
